# Jquery yesconflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

I have a website based on a joomla template. I want to add the dock from

ndesign-studio.com/blog/mac/css-dock-menu

I've built a sample page for this.

Here is the code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="images/eklenecek/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="images/eklenecek/interface.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            $("#dock").Fisheye(
                {
                    maxWidth: 30,
                    items: "a",
                    itemsText: "span",
                    container: ".dock-container",
                    itemWidth: 30,
                    proximity: 100,
                    halign : "center"
                }
            )
        }
    );

</script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.dock {
    position: relative; 
    height: 50px; 
    text-align: center;
}
.dock-container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
a.dock-item {
    display: block;
    width: 48px;
    color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.dock-item img {
    border: none; 
    margin: 5px 10px 0px; 
    width: 100%; 
}
.dock-item span {
    display: none; 
    padding-left: 20px;
}
-->
</style>

<div class="dock" id="dock">
  <div class="dock-container">
  <a class="dock-item" href="#"><img src="images/eklenecek/email.png" alt="home" /><span>E-Posta ile Gonder</span></a> 
  <a class="dock-item" href="#"><img src="images/eklenecek/print.png" alt="contact" /><span>Yazdir</span></a> 
  <a class="dock-item" href="#"><img src="images/eklenecek/fav.png" alt="portfolio" /><span>Portfolio</span></a> 
  <a class="dock-item" href="#"><img src="images/eklenecek/pdf.png" alt="music" /><span>Music</span></a> 
  <a class="dock-item" href="#"><img src="images/eklenecek/blogger.png" alt="video" /><span>Video</span></a> 
  <a class="dock-item" href="#"><img src="images/eklenecek/delicious.png" alt="history" /><span>History</span></a> 
  <a class="dock-item" href="#"><img src="images/eklenecek/digg.png" alt="calendar" /><span>Calendar</span></a> 
  <a class="dock-item" href="#"><img src="images/eklenecek/facebook.png" alt="rss" /><span>RSS</span></a>
  <a class="dock-item" href="#"><img src="images/eklenecek/friendfeed.png" alt="rss" /><span>RSS</span></a> 
  <a class="dock-item" href="#"><img src="images/eklenecek/google.png" alt="rss" /><span>RSS</span></a> 
  <a class="dock-item" href="#"><img src="images/eklenecek/habergentr.png" alt="rss" /><span>RSS</span></a> 
  <a class="dock-item" href="#"><img src="images/eklenecek/myspace.png" alt="rss" /><span>RSS</span></a> 
  <a class="dock-item" href="#"><img src="images/eklenecek/stumbleupon.png" alt="rss" /><span>RSS</span></a> 
  <a class="dock-item" href="#"><img src="images/eklenecek/twitter.png" alt="rss" /><span>RSS</span></a> 
  <a class="dock-item" href="#"><img src="images/eklenecek/yahoo.png" alt="rss" /><span>RSS</span></a>   
</div>
</div>
```

This one works great!

My question is, when i put the code into the addthis.php of the joomla addthis plugin, it doesn't work. Here is the final html of the code, I've commented the less-important parts:

[TAKE A LOOK AT THE CODE, IT IS TOO BIG TO PASTE HERE](http://www.students.itu.edu.tr/~ozyildiri2/a.html)

I think it is about

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        $("#dock").Fisheye(
            {
                maxWidth: 30,
                items: "a",
                itemsText: "span",
                container: ".dock-container",
                itemWidth: 30,
                proximity: 100,
                halign : "center"
            }
        )
    }
);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could have a lot to do with you loading Mootools and JQuery in the same page, have a look at this [link](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/07/jquerynoconflict-resolving-conflicts.html), I think it could help.

In effect your code will become:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        $("#dock").Fisheye(
            {
                maxWidth: 30,
                items: "a",
                itemsText: "span",
                container: ".dock-container",
                itemWidth: 30,
                proximity: 100,
                halign : "center"
            }
        )
    }
);
```

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't work. If you look at the big code, there is already a line that says : 

<script type="text/javascript" >if (jQuery && jQuery.noConflict) jQuery.noConflict();</script>

Comment: True but your code still has $(document).ready rather than jQuery(document).ready

Comment: Add to that, all your paths for javascript refer to http://localhost or have the root '/' as the start of the path rather than being relative paths or referring to the server that is the actual source for these files. As a result you have no jQuery, mooTools or anything else loaded.

Comment: I know this. The a.html is just the html source loaded to another server because I couldn't paste it here.

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug with Firefox to load the page and looking at the errors reported by the Console therein?

Comment: The localhost references will cause the machine running the browser to look for the files on itself rather than the server so unless it's the same box, it's going to fail.

Comment: This is what Firebug says : jQuery("#dock").Fisheye is not a function

Comment: I've figured it out. It is because i put the interface.js before jquery. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you DO realize that your page is NOT properly formated html with the commented out section starting with:

```
<!--<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html
```

EDIT: second note why the `</span>` right after the quoted script you note????

EDIT: third note:  I would change

```
<script type="text/javascript" >if (jQuery && jQuery.noConflict) jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

to be

```
<script type="text/javascript" > jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

Here is what I see on the page (as of when I looked at least)
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; MDDR; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3; OfficeLivePatch.0.0)
Timestamp: Tue, 9 Feb 2010 13:06:38 UTC

Message: Syntax error
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://www.students.itu.edu.tr/media/system/js/mootools.js

Message: Syntax error
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://www.students.itu.edu.tr/media/system/js/caption.js

Message: Syntax error
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://www.students.itu.edu.tr/modules/mod_jamegamenu/assets/script.js

Message: Syntax error
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://www.students.itu.edu.tr/modules/mod_janewsticker/assets/script.js

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 30
Char: 20
Code: 0
URI: http://www.students.itu.edu.tr/~ozyildiri2/a.html

Message: 'Cufon' is undefined
Line: 74
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://www.students.itu.edu.tr/~ozyildiri2/a.html

Message: 'jQuery' is undefined
Line: 89
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://www.students.itu.edu.tr/~ozyildiri2/a.html

Message: Object expected
Line: 168
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: http://www.students.itu.edu.tr/~ozyildiri2/a.html

Message: Object expected
Line: 383
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://www.students.itu.edu.tr/~ozyildiri2/a.html

Message: 'jaSLWI' is undefined
Line: 434
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: http://www.students.itu.edu.tr/~ozyildiri2/a.html

Message: Object expected
Line: 615
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://www.students.itu.edu.tr/~ozyildiri2/a.html

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 634
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://www.students.itu.edu.tr/~ozyildiri2/a.html

Comment: This errors are because I've only uploaded a sample html from my localhost to another server to show you. I wasn't able to paste that much code.

Comment: so, first, just make the HTML proper HTML by removing the comment that starts the page to see if it loads, fix that span issue and see if it works then...as is, the sample HTML page in your link is just a real mess and not really much help if it does not match the real page.

Comment: I've figured it out. It is because i put the interface.js before jquery. thank you.